# Error al instalar firebase-admin

Tags: python, firebase, pip

un cordial saludo, quiero pedir su ayuda, actualmente estoy intentado instalar el paquete ***firebaseadmin*** para ello estoy siguiendo la documentación de firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?hl=es-419, ellos me indican que use el comando

```
pip install --upgrade firebase-admin
```

Sin embargo me aparece el siguiente error (Ver imagen 1 para ver error completo)

```
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego de leer el hilo descrito en el mensaje el cual es
 https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599
He seguido algunas instrucciones para solucionar el problema, pero aun no lo logro.

use el comando (1) para ver la versión de **pip**

`python -m pip --version`

el cual me devolvió

`pip 20.0 from /home/chaquen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

tambien use el comando (2) para ver la version de pip de python3
`python3 -m pip --version`
el cual devolvió

`pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`

En un foro me indicaron que usar el comando 
`sudo python3 -m pip install firebase-admin` pero tampoco funciono

No se si he interpretado mal o me equivoco pero creo que mi error radica en la instalación de pip al comparar los **comando 1 y 2** ya que la ruta es diferente, por eso quiero pedirles la ayuda para saber como solucionar este problema que debería cambiar y como hacerlo. De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

El equipo donde estoy intentando hacer la prueba tiene

Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

python --version
Python 2.7.17

python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

Comment: Primero, te recomiendo abandonar Python 2.x está en EOL desde Enero.Actualiza `pip` primero `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` y luego intenta con `python3 -m pip install --user firebase-admin` . Si sale alguna excepción compártela.  Lo suyo es que crearas un entorno virtual y no instalaras en las versiones del sistema de Python. También puedes usar pyenv para instalar las versiones que te de la gana independientemente de lo que la distro ofrezca,

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda, te comento realice la actualización de **pip** y luego cree un entorno virtual y desde allí pude instalar firebase-admin y funciono correctamente